# EF 6 Returning stale information from new context?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

Class RBI.Lead:

```
Public Class Lead
#Region "Constructors "
Public Sub New()
    _cxt = New RDB.RDBContainer
    _person = New RDB.Lead
End Sub

Public Sub New(ID As Guid)
    If Not IsNothing(ID) Then
        If IsNothing(_cxt) Then _cxt = New RDB.RDBContainer
        If IsNothing(_person) Then
            _person = _cxt.Leads.Find(ID)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
#End Region
...
 Public ReadOnly Property Notes As IEnumerable(Of RBI.PersonNote)
    Get
        If Not IsNothing(_person.LeadNotes) Then
            Dim _tmp As IEnumerable(Of RiseBI.LeadNote) = _person.PersonNote.Select(Function(p) New RBI.PersonNote(p, _cxt))
            Return _tmp.ToList
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Get
End Property
...
End Class
```

RDB.Lead:

```
Partial Public Class Lead
    Public Property Id As System.Guid
    ...        
    Public Overridable Property LeadNotes As ICollection(Of LeadNote) = New HashSet(Of LeadNote)
End Class
```

Adding a new note to a Lead:

```
 Public Shared Function AddNote(ID As Guid, Note As String) As Guid
    Dim _cxt As New RDB.RDBContainer
    Dim _tmp As New RDB.PersonNote
    Dim _person = DB.Leads.Find(ID)
    _tmp .Id = Guid.NewGuid()
    _tmp .Note = Note
    _lead.LeadNotes.Add(tmp)
    DB.SaveChanges()
    Return _tmp.ID
End Function
```

The UI side of things:
Adding a new note:

```
 Protected Sub modNotes_save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnModalNotes.Click
    LeadFunctions.AddNote(Guid.Parse(RouteData.Values("pid")), txtModalNotes.Text)
    PHSuccess.Visible = True
    lblMasterSuccess.Text = "Notes updated"
    listNotes.Rebind()
End Sub
```

Where ListNotes datasource is defined as:

```
     Protected Sub ListNotes_NeedDataSource(sender As Object, e As RadListViewNeedDataSourceEventArgs)
     Dim _person As New RiseBI.Lead(CStr(RouteData.Values("pid")))
     ListNotes.DataSource = _person.Notes
End Sub
```

When a note is added, it appears in the DB. However even though the listview is rebind it displays old data, not the new data.

Comment: I have no idea what this is about. I don't see a UI side. The function and location of these `New` subs and the `Notes` property is totally unclear. You show some random bits and pieces and ask a question that doesn't seem related to any of these. The only thing I see is a `Note` is added to the database and its guid as the only trace left to the application. How would a listview be able to display this new object?

Comment: Sorry. I have edited it to be more clear